# Head First Java example explanation needed

Tags: java

Hi! I'm reading Head First Java and i can't understand the behaviour of the following code:

```
public class Dog {
    String name;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // make a Dog object and access it
        Dog dog1 = new Dog();
        dog1.bark();
        dog1.name = "Bart";

        // now make a Dog array
        Dog[] myDogs = new Dog[3];
        // and put some dogs in it
        myDogs[0] = new Dog();
        myDogs[1] = new Dog();
        myDogs[2] = dog1;

        // now acces the Dogs using the array references
        myDogs[0].name = "Fred";
        myDogs[1].name = "Marge";

        // Hmmm... what is MyDogs[2] name?
        System.out.print("last dog name is ");
        System.out.println(myDogs[2].name);

        // now loop through the array
        // and tell all dogs to bark
        int x = 0;
        while (x < myDogs.length) {
            myDogs[x].bark();
            x = x + 1;
        }
    }

    public void bark() {
        System.out.println(name + " says Ruff!");
    }
```

The output produced by this code is the following:

```
null says Ruff!
last dog name is Bart
Fred says Ruff!
Marge says Ruff!
Bart says Ruff!
```

I have a very hard time understanding this, IMO the code should run to somekind of infinite loop. From what i understand (and i've previously programmed in python): When the class is acticated, the main method gets called, and then inside the main method, two more classes of the same type are created. (Now here comes the incomprehensible part -->) When the new class is created, inside it's main method, 2 more classes are created and so on .. How can it be that it produces the output shown above, when it creates an infinte number of classes, so the code should actually never finish running.

Thank you!

Comment: I would step through the code in your debugger to understand what it is doing.

Comment: Main() is not a constructor and calling a constructor doesn't call main().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've posted just instantiates a total of 3 instances of the `Dog` class. The `myDogs` array has 3 elements, so the `while` loop is guaranteed to terminate.
What's not clear?

The `main` method is called only when executing the program. Your program could have been written like this (more clear for a Java beginner, I think):

```
class Dog {
    String name;
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println(name + " says Ruff!");
    }
}

public class MyDogTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // make a Dog object and access it
        Dog dog1 = new Dog();
        dog1.bark();
        dog1.name = "Bart";

        // now make a Dog array
        Dog[] myDogs = new Dog[3];
        // and put some dogs in it
        myDogs[0] = new Dog();
        myDogs[1] = new Dog();
        myDogs[2] = dog1;

        // now acces the Dogs using the array references
        myDogs[0].name = "Fred";
        myDogs[1].name = "Marge";

        // Hmmm... what is MyDogs[2] name?
        System.out.print("last dog name is ");
        System.out.println(myDogs[2].name);

        // now loop through the array
        // and tell all dogs to bark
        int x = 0;
        while (x < myDogs.length) {
            myDogs[x].bark();
            x = x + 1;
        }

    }

}
```

If you put the two classes (`Dog` and `MyDogTest`) inside the same `.java` file, please note that only `MyDogTest` should be declared as `public`, otherwise the program won't compile.

Comment: Oh, thank you everyone. I thought that main() in java acted the way __init__ method does in Python clases..

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding the `main()` method.

Java calls the `main()` method when you start executing a program.
Instantiating a class does not run the `main()` method; it will just run the class's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Instantiating a class will call the constructor of the class. You didn't define one, so your constructor is actually one without parameters and without body, like this:

```
public Dog () {

}
```

Of course, this constructor will never cause an infinite loop.

The main method is the one called when starting your program and thus called exactly once.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the `static` keyword in the `main()` method declaration. It means that the method is always accessible, unrelated to a specific class instance. (Since you come from  Python world, you are welcome to read a bit about the [field modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldModifiers.html)).
You can in a way observe it as "an external" method (meaning you can always access it externally and execute it with `Dog.main(your string args)`), that is not "aware" of the class existence. Also notice that multiple classes that you use can have `main` method, in which case you should decide which one is the really the main one, by declaring it in the `manifest` file, but this is a bit advanced topic, that is left for your further research.
And of course, as the others already explained, `main` method is a specific method that the JVM runs once, in the moment you execute your program.